# Convert STAR XSD to C# classes

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe, xsdobjectgen

I have been trying to create a STAR standards compliant webservice (ASMX of course) . My service will accept a the an object "ProcessPartsActivity"  which is defined as an XSD "ProcessPartsActivity.xsd".

STAR XSD: [STAR XSD DownLoad](http://www.starstandard.org/uploads/SIGXMLSTAR5/STARSchemaRepository_Rev554.zip)

This XSD is making use of a number of other XSDs inside. The [STAR FAQ](http://www.starstandard.org/SIGXML/XMLSchemasFAQs#toc12) indicates that using XSDObjectGen instead of XSD to create C# classes.

I have been trying to convert the XSDs into C# objects using XSD.EXE and XSDObjectGen but both are encountering schema validation error.

```
XSDObjectGen.exe "<folder path>\ProcessPartsActivity.xsd" /l:cs /n:"DummyNamespace"

XSD.exe "<folder path>\ProcessPartsActivity.xsd"
```

Has anyone converted these XSDs to C# classes before or if there are other methods to achieve please suggest.

[ProcessPartsActivity INFO](http://www.starstandard.org/uploads/SIGXMLSTAR4/AcknowledgePartsInventory.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still did not get what was the real issue with XSD.EXE and XSDObjectGen but this seems to work properly in VS 2012 Xsd2Code 3.6 Version.

[Xsd2Code 3.6 link](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/releases/view/98851)

I am able to successfully generate code from the STAR standards XSDs (with more than one nested schema imports files)

Comment: To get this to work, I copied the nested STAR directory structure containing the XSDs into my project and added them "as link".